# Using unity's A* pathfinding plugin but the AI doesn't move or moves in a wrong direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding

I'm learning to use the [A* pathfinding plugin](http://arongranberg.com/astar/). I've successfully made a demo on an X/Z plane. As the project I'm working on is actually a 2D game, I want to use the plugin on the X/Y plane. However, while it works perfectly on an X/Z plane, it doesn't work well on the X/Y plane.

**All the scripts used,`AstarPath.cs`,`Seeker.cs`,`AIPath.cs`, are the original scripts from the `A* pathfinding project` and the version is `v3.7`.**

Then I followed these [instructions](http://hobblygobbly.tumblr.com/post/93960257057/how-to-setup-the-a-pathfinding-project-in-a-2d).

When I click `Run` to run the game, the AI does calculate a correct path:
[image]

but then the AI moves in the wrong direction:

[image]

When it moves, it also keeps calculating its path. What should I change to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

AIPath.cs is hard-coded for the XZ plane. You will need to either make your game on the XZ plane, modify AIPath.cs, or create your own path-following script. Tell me if you would like guidance on how to do this.

Comment: Actually I'm new to unity, so it seems a little difficult to create my own script. But I'd like to have a try, could you please give some advice?

Comment: I think that implementing libraries from other people is not the place to start.    This page has a bunch of tutorials from Unity itself to get started with using Unity https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials . Otherwise, I think you don't have to understand how the AIPath script works to switch .y and .z .